# Katharsis with standard spring mvc controller for posting JSON returns 400

Tags: json, spring-mvc, spring-boot, katharsis

I've integrated Katharsis with spring-boot (MVC + Security) and I'm realy happy about it.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(KatharsisConfigV2.class)
@Configuration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I began to setup security with an extra spring mvc controller to handle login and logout methods.

But with a RequestBody annotated parameters to convert json to java object, I've got a 400 response telling me required body is missing.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody AuthenticationResponse signup(
        @RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) {
    ...
}
```

When I remove the import for Katharsis configuration, everything goes fine.

```
@SpringBootApplication
//@Import(KatharsisConfigV2.class)
@Configuration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

How could I tweak my project configuration to allow basics spring controllers to accept standard JSON?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nobody can help you when you don't show your code.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact message in the `"detail"` field of the [response](http://jsonapi.org/examples/#error-objects-basics)?  [Katharsis-Spring](https://github.com/katharsis-project/katharsis-spring) provides decent error details.  That should provide you a better idea of exactly what's wrong.

Remember that `POST` bodies in JSON API will [differ from how they look in regular Spring](http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-creating), e.g. there needs to be a `"data"` field in your payload.

You may also need to configure Katharsis in your `application.properties` file.  Katharsis can't process requests unless it's [configured properly](http://katharsis-jsonapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-docs.html#spring-integration).

Hope this helps.